# cant fillter characters in jcombo

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, jcombobox

Can someone help me with this? My sql code only works if I match only integers like 2=2 but if I change it to like this orange=orange it wont work...can anyone help me figure whats wrong with my code.

**index.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jCombo.min.js"></script>
<form>
Caraga Region: <select name="region" id="region"></select>
Municipalities: <select name="town" id="town"></select>
Unique ID: <select name="uniq_id" id="uniq_id"></select> <br />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
   $("#region").jCombo({ url: "getRegion.php" } );
   $("#town").jCombo({ url: "getTown.php?townid=", parent: "#region", selected_value : '510' } );
   $("#uniq_id").jCombo({ url: "getID.php?unqid=", parent: "#town", data: String, selected_value : '150' } );
});
</script>
```

**getRegion.php:**

```
<?php

    // Connect Database
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");     
    mysql_select_db("klayton");

    // Execute Query in the right order  
    //(value,text)
    $query = "SELECT id, municipalities FROM regions";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $option = array("id" => $row[0], "value" => htmlentities($row[1]));
            $items[] = $option; 
        }        
    }
    mysql_close();
    $data = json_encode($items); 
    // convert into JSON format and print
    $response = isset($_GET['callback'])?$_GET['callback']."(".$data.")":$data; 
    echo $data;
?>
```

**getTown.php:**

```
<?php 

// Connect Database 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("klayton"); 

// Get parameters from Array 

$townid = !empty($_GET['townid']) 
?intval($_GET['townid']):0;
// if there is no city selected by GET, fetch all rows 
$query = "SELECT town FROM towns WHERE tcode = $townid"; 

// fetch the results 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$items = array(); 
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$option = array("id" => $row['town'], "value" => htmlentities($row['town'])); 
$items[] = $option; 
} 
}
    mysql_close();
    $data = json_encode($items); 
    echo $data;
?>
```

**getID.php:** The problem is in this code. It wont work if I match character to character it only works if its `integer=integer`.

```
<?php 

// Connect Database 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("klayton"); 

// Get parameters from Array 

$unqid = !empty($_GET['unqid']) 
?intval($_GET['unqid']):0;
// if there is no city selected by GET, fetch all rows 
$query = "SELECT uid, unq_pos_id FROM tb_uniqid WHERE tb_uniqid.uid = '$unqid'"; 

// fetch the results 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$items = array(); 
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$option = array("id" => $row['uid'], "value" => htmlentities($row['unq_pos_id'])); 
$items[] = $option; 
} 
}
    mysql_close();
    $data = json_encode($items); 
    echo $data;
?>
```

(uid)field is stored with character values just like in the (town)field. I want to match it but it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to in *getID.php* replace:

```
$unqid = !empty($_GET['unqid']) 
?intval($_GET['unqid']):0;
```

with:

```
$unqid = !empty($_GET['unqid']) 
?$_GET['unqid']:0;
```

if you want to be able to match strings as well as integers. You see, `intval()` returns only the integer value of the variable, thus you strip of the other characters when you send a string to that page, and therefore you can't match anything with the code you had before.